# Why does variable initialization and assigning value to an existing variable yield different results in Javascript console?

Tags: javascript

So, while experimenting in the Chrome JS Console, I found something which is a bit puzzling.

When I run, the following in the console, the console prints `undefined`

```
var i = 10;
```

However, when I run this, it prints `10`:

```
j = 10
```

Here is a screenshot of the results in my console.

[image: Sample]

Could anyone explain to me why this difference in behavior?

Comment: `var i = 10` is a statement. `j = 10` is an expression.

Comment: but both of these are using the `=` operator, so I though the behaviour should be same

Comment: They don't do the same thing. `j = 10` assumes `j` exists already, and if not it will create an implicit global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the fundamental difference between statements and expressions. Expressions evaluate to something, statements don't.

`var j = 10;` is a statement (a [variable statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement) specifically), so it does not evaluate to anything and can only be used in statement contexts.

`j = 10` is an expression, so it evaluates to a value and can be included anywhere a value is expected (EG. `if ( j = 10 )` or `console.log( j = 10 )`). Any expression can also be used on its own in a statement context since there is a type of statement called an [expression statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-expression-statement).

In a REPL (read,evaluate,print,loop), such as Chrome's console, the result of an expression statement is printed immediately after it is evaluated, other statements such as a variable statement don't evaluate to anything so a REPL can't print anything, or, in Chrome's case, prints `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome will print the return value of the code you enter. This means what it prints is equivalent to `console.log(WHAT_YOU_ENTER);`. As commented by @elclanrs (upvoted), it's a difference between an expression `j = 10` and a statement `var i = 10`.

Answer (score 0):

The console will print the result of evaluating an expression. The result of evaluating `var i = 10` is `undefined` since `var` does not explicitly return something.

You can observe the same behavior with many expressions:

```
> console.loe(10);
10
undefined;
```

An assignment expression does not produce a value so again `undefined` is printed to the console.

As a counter-example, expressions containing mathematical operators do produce a value which is printed to the console instead of `undefined`:

```
> j = 10;
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaration does not return a value, so var i = 10 returns undefined
On the other hand, j = 10, is an assignment, which returns a value, so the console  returns that value.

Answer (score 0):

var i = 10 is just a statement.
It is assigning a value to variable i.
It is just declaration.It does not return a value.
when you print it it will give you an answer 10.

[image]

while if you write k = 10. It works as an expression. it will assign and return value.